# Let $I = (x^2, y)$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ show that Rad$(I)$ = $(x,y)$ and $I$ is a primary ideal that is not a power of a prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $I = (x^2, y)$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ show that Rad$(I)$ = $(x,y)$ and $I$ is a primary ideal that is not a power of a prime ideal.

I can see that $(x,y) \subset Rad(I)$ b/c $x^1, y^2 \in (x,y^2)$

Further $x \in (x,y)$ and $y^2 \in (x,y)$ so this clearly gives $(x,y^2) \subset (x,y)$ and $(x,y)$ is maximal thus $Rad(I) \subset (x,y)$ hence they are equal. 
For $I$ is primary: since $Rad(I) = (x,y)$, Rad$(I)$ is maximal

I think the correct course is $I$ is primary if every zero-divisor in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$  is nilpotent

Comment: It is not true that $(x,y^2)$ is a prime ideal, since $y^2$ is an element of it, whereas $y$ is not. In fact, the quotient ring $\mathbb Q[x,y]/(x,y^2) \cong \mathbb Q[y]/(y^2)$ is Artin local with unique prime ideal $(y)$.

Comment: @Engloutie ah yes I will take that out, starting over.